# Creating an XML file in OpenCV

Tags: c, xml, opencv

I have created an XML file, but when I try to read it in I get an error about a duplicate key. When I opened the XML file I noticed that nothing was nested and everything was treated as it's own individual node. I was wondering if there was a way to properly create the XML file and be able to parse through it as well. Below I have included my code for writing an XML file out, my XML output, and what I would like it to be.

XML Code:

```
// Open up the file so that we can write to it
cv::FileStorage fs;
fs.open(szFileName, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

// Check if we actually created the file
if(fs.isOpened())
{
    fs << "Total_Images" << (int)vImages.size();
    //cv::write(fs, "Total Images", (int)vImages.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)vImages.size(); i++)
    {
        char szSize[8];
        string szNode;
        szNode = "image_";
        itoa(i, szSize, 10);
        szNode += szSize;

        fs << "Node" << szNode;
        fs << "Width" << vImages[i]->GetWidth();
        fs << "Height" << vImages[i]->GetHeight();
        fs << "Keypoint_Size" << (int)vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints().size();

        for(int j = 0; j < vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints().size(); j++)
        {
            char szSize[256];
            fs << "Angle" << vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints()[j].angle;
            fs << "Class" << vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints()[j].class_id;
            fs << "Octave" << vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints()[j].octave;
            fs << "Pt_X" << vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints()[j].pt.x;
            fs << "Pt_Y" << vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints()[j].pt.y;
            fs << "Response" << vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints()[j].response;
            fs << "Size" << vImages[i]->GetKeyPoints()[j].size;
        }

        fs << "Descriptors" << vImages[i]->GetDescriptors();
    }

    fs.release();
}
```

XML Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<Total_Images>1</Total_Images>
<Node>image_0</Node>
<Width>500</Width>
<Height>266</Height>
<Keypoint_Size>268</Keypoint_Size>
<Angle>8.7332672119140625e+001</Angle>
<Class>0</Class>
<Octave>-1</Octave>
<Pt_X>1.7401049804687500e+002</Pt_X>
<Pt_Y>6.5084960937500000e+001</Pt_Y>
<Response>0.</Response>
<Size>1.1386331558227539e+001</Size>
<Angle>9.3859291076660156e+001</Angle>
<Class>0</Class>
<Octave>-1</Octave>
<Pt_X>1.7674386596679687e+002</Pt_X>
<Pt_Y>6.4983604431152344e+001</Pt_Y>
<Response>0.</Response>
<Size>1.2262072563171387e+001</Size>
<Angle>9.8604904174804688e+001</Angle>
<Class>0</Class>
<Octave>-1</Octave>
<Pt_X>1.1859683990478516e+002</Pt_X>
<Pt_Y>6.6855834960937500e+001</Pt_Y>
<Response>0.</Response>
<Size>1.1112688064575195e+001</Size>
...
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<Total_Images>1</Total_Images>
<Node>image_0
    <Width>500</Width>
    <Height>266</Height>
    <Keypoint_Size>268</Keypoint_Size>
    <KeyPoint>
            <Angle>8.7332672119140625e+001</Angle>
        <Class>0</Class>
        <Octave>-1</Octave>
        <Pt_X>1.7401049804687500e+002</Pt_X>
        <Pt_Y>6.5084960937500000e+001</Pt_Y>
        <Response>0.</Response>
        <Size>1.1386331558227539e+001</Size>
    </KeyPoint>
    <KeyPoint>
        <Angle>9.3859291076660156e+001</Angle>
        <Class>0</Class>
        <Octave>-1</Octave>
        <Pt_X>1.7674386596679687e+002</Pt_X>
        <Pt_Y>6.4983604431152344e+001</Pt_Y>
        <Response>0.</Response>
        <Size>1.2262072563171387e+001</Size>
    </KeyPoint>
    <KeyPoint>
        <Angle>9.8604904174804688e+001</Angle>
        <Class>0</Class>
        <Octave>-1</Octave>
        <Pt_X>1.1859683990478516e+002</Pt_X>
        <Pt_Y>6.6855834960937500e+001</Pt_Y>
        <Response>0.</Response>
        <Size>1.1112688064575195e+001</Size>
    </KeyPoint>
    ...
</Node>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embedd a node inside another node.
Do it like this (using "{" and "}" ):

```
FileStorage fs;  // Open it and check that it is opened;

fs << "SimpleData"  << 1;

fs << "Structure << "{";
fs << "firstField"  << 1;
fs << "secondField"  << 2;
fs << "}"; // End of structure node

fs << "SimpleData2"  << 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually we can see the "Duplicated key" error in opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp line 711 
The key seems have sth to do with the node name in your xml file: once you have many nodes with the same name like below,it will has duplicated key.And even you haven't read but just open this file,it will occur.So, just modify your node names,how about add an index "node_1"?

```
<opencv_storage>
<mynodes>
    <node>1</node>
    <node>2</node>
    <node>3</node>
    <node>4</node>
    ...
    <node>10</node>
</mynodes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use JSON which is more fash and simple to interpret

Comment: If I knew how the cv::Mat structure was arranged I would personally write my data out in binary.

Comment: Great, then all you need to do is check Mat's documentation and write down everything you want to save from it: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat

Comment: @karlphillip - I check that doc so many times but it still doesn't explain much to me. I have an example matrix that has 268 rows and 128 columns that is saved as a type 5. I am not sure what a type 5 is exactly and when writing out to a binary format I need to take the size into account and try a "sizeof(5)" probably won't work

Comment: According to `OpenCV-2.3.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h` , type 5 is `CV_32F`, meaning that the data is stored as 32-bit *float*. By the way, since the docs s*ck, if you want to be good at OpenCV you need to become comfortable searching stuff in OpenCV sources.

Answer (score 0):

File storage is not designed for this type of use, however you can use a XML-parser/writter, the easiest, fastest and most fashion one is Xerces-C. [You can download it here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)

Actually, the filestorage object is made to store simple datas like calibration from one runtime to the other... From what i know there is no way to structure the nodes between each others...

Julien,

**EDIT :**

*READ DATA FROM A MAT*

```
for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++) {
    unsigned char* row = img.data + i * img.step;
    for(int j=0;j<img.cols;j++) {
    unsigned char* channB = (row + 3*j);
    unsigned char* channG = (row + 3*j + 1);
    unsigned char* channR = (row + 3*j + 2);
    }
}
```

*WRITE WITH XERCES-C*

- The ["DOMPrint" example](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/domprint-2.html) shows how to write in a document with a serializer...

However, let me tell you that i think that OpenCV is enough for your example, is it a big problem that yuor datas are in nodes next to each other ? I'll try to find an easier way, let me think of it, i'll post back here (still, you sould try Xerces-C it's great and usefull)

Comment: I was really hoping to use OpenCV for I/O since it handles cv::Mat data, but if I have no choice but to get an external API for XML writing I would like to know how I would write out and read in the cv::Mat data and be able to create the data from it.

Comment: It's not a huge problem it just returns an error stating that there are duplicate keys when I try to read the data in. I figured the format would throw that error. Not sure if I have to use the FileNode class and iterate each node. If so I'm going to need to find an example of somewhere that does that.

Comment: Jmartel, you are wrong. File Storage is perfect for xml writing. See my answer of how to make node inside node