# Reading nested XML in OpenCV

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, file-io

This stackoverflow question answers how to write data into an XML file with nesting:
[Creating an XML file in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874343/creating-an-xml-file-in-opencv)

With Reference to the same question (and the accepted answer), how would I read the same file using the FileStorage class?

In short, how do I read the data the following code snippet writes?

```
FileStorage fs;  // Open it and check that it is opened;

fs << "SimpleData"  << 1;

fs << "Structure" << "{";
fs << "firstField"  << 1;
fs << "secondField"  << 2;
fs << "}"; // End of structure node

fs << "SimpleData2"  << 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
FileStorage fs;
fs.open(filename, FileStorage::READ);

int SimpleData = (int) fs["SimpleData"];

FileNode n = fs["Structure"];  // Read Structure sequence - Get node
int firstField = (int)(n["firstField"]);
int secondField = (int)(n["secondField"]);

int SimpleData2 = (int) fs["SimpleData2"];
```

Check out [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out today and accept as answer if it works :)